# C language: I want to see if a value of a[] is less than all the values of b[]

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop

I have to solve an exercise in C. The exercise asks me to get 2 arrays (a, b) from input and see if there is a value of a[] which is less than all the values of b.
Both array have 3 elements. 
The code I wrote is the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    while(k<3)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[k])
        {
            count++;
            if (count==3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    count=0;
}

if (count==3)
{
    printf("TRUE");
}
else
{
    printf("FALSE");
}
```

The problem with the code is that it prints false in any input I give.
Any help would be appreciated. 
P.S. I left out the scanning from keyboard of the arrays and the declaration of i and k to keep the code short and clearer.

Comment: You are resetting `count = 0;` at the end of every iteration of the `for` loop

Comment: Please read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm doing this so count doesnt give =3 even if a[i] isnt less than every b[k]. Do you have a suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: `if(count=3)` assigns count to three. you probably want `==` to compare instead

Comment: @Andreas sorry, In the editor is correct but I messed up copying the code

Comment: @UnholySheep They thought me how to debug, I'm just not making it with this one

Comment: @DillonWreek stackoverflow is no place for friendly discussions in the comment field. You will be ripped wide open by trolls if you try to. Ask your question, wait for at least 1hr, review comments and answers, then focus on the most useful response. Ignore everything else.

Comment: @Andreas lol thanks for the tip

Comment: your question is not straight forward, is it that every index element of `a` should be greater than that same corresponding index in `b` or the total of the values in a should be greater that the total values in b

Comment: Find the min in b and check it against the numbers in a. It is pretty simple.

Comment: Search the minimum of a and the minimum of b. Then ...

Answer (score 2):

For starters do not use magic numbers like 3. Instead use named constants.

In this statement

```
if(a[i]<a[k])
```

you are comparing elements of the same array `a` instead of comparing an element of `a` with an element of the array `b`.

Also before the while loop you have to set the variables `count` and `k` to 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    k = 0;
    count = 0;
    while(k<3)
```

And the break statement breaks the while loop but it does not break the outer for loop.

The code does not determine the position of the target element of the array `a` that is less than all elements of the array `b`.

You could write a separate function that does the task.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t find_less_than( const int a[], const int b[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( _Bool found = 0; !found && i < n; i += !found )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( j < n && a[i] < b[j] ) j++;

        found = j == n;
    }

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };

    int a[N], b[N];

    printf( "Enter %d values of the array a: ", N );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &a[i] );

    printf( "Enter %d values of the array b: ", N );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &b[i] );

    size_t i = find_less_than( a, b, N );
    if ( i != N )
    {
        printf( "The element at position %zu with the value %d of the array a\n"
                "is less than all elements of the array b\n", i, a[i] );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "There is no element in the array a\n"
              "that is less than all elements of the array b\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter 3 values of the array a: 3 0 1
Enter 3 values of the array b: 1 2 3
The element at position 1 with the value 0 of the array a
is less than all elements of the array b
```

Comment: many thanks for your in depth explanation! Although I see you're using commands we have yet to learn (eg. enum and size_t) but I've fully understood what you mean, Many thanks for giving out such detailed answer!

Comment: @Dillon Wreek Instead of the enum you can use the directive #define N 3 before main.

Answer (score 1):

Writing programs is mechanics. Of course, it seems challenging at first, but it rapidly becomes easier; you only need to translate the description of a solution ("first do this, then do that") into a programming language.

The real art is coming up with good solutions. A good solution does not waste time or space, for example. And it also scales to larger problems.

In this problem, the obvious solution is to take each element in turn from `a` and see if it is less than every element of `b`. In the worst case, that will involve comparing every element of `a` with every element of `b`. That doesn't matter much if they both only have three elements, but suppose they had a million elements. Then that procedure could end up comparing every element of `a` with every element of `b`, a total of 1,000,000,000,000 comparisons. Even on modern hardware, that would take a long time.

But there is an easy improvement. If an element from `a` is not less than any element of `b`, then it is not less than the smallest element of `b`. Conversely, if it is less than every element of `b`, then it is obviously less than the smallest element of `b`.

So it is not necessary to compare with every element of `b`; only with the smallest element of `b`. We don't initially know what that element is, but it is straight-forward to scan `b` once to find it, and then use it in a scan of `a`. That lets us solve the million element problem with at most 1,999,999 comparisons, which I think you will agree is a lot more practical.

Sometimes nested loops are necessary. But when you see one, you should always at least ask yourself, "is there a better solution?" Because the art and joy of programming isn't the mechanical translation of algorithm into code; it is the eureka moment in which that better solution reveals itself to you.

Comment: This approach does not allow to find the first element that is less than all elements of another array.

Comment: @vlad:why not? You find `min(b)`; then the linear scan of `a` will find the first element of `a` which is less than any element of `b`. (I did not say "find the minima of `a` and `b`" for precisely that reason).

Comment: Oh, I have understood.:)

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is a value in a that is less than all the values of b, you can use a double for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    int count= 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        if(a[i]<b[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count==3) break;
}
if (i<3) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```

---

Another approach, which is faster, is to first find the smallest of `a` and then check for each `b` if this is smaller:

```
int smallest= a[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
    if (a[i]<smallest) smallest=a[i];

int count= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    if(<b[i]<smallest)
        count++;

if (count==3) printf("yes\n");
```

The first version has a nested loop, and so has n*n iterations. The second has only n+n iterations (also called O(n<sup>2</sup>) and O(n+n)).

Comment: O(n*m) solution to O(n+m) problem. This should at least be mentioned.